# Use homebrew packages in Jenkins in MacOSX

Tags: macos, jenkins, homebrew

How do I enable, somehow, my Jenkins instance (installed via homebrew) to use the packages that I've installed via homebrew. For example I can't call git from a SH job in Jenkins because I'v installed Git ia homebrew and due that this package (Git) is not available to the Jenkins user.

Below I'm trying to call `brew` for test and I'm getting a error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /var/root/.jenkins/workspace/sandbox
[sandbox] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/jenkins2268498674034232648.sh
+ brew
/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/jenkins2268498674034232648.sh: line 2: brew: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Should I had install homebrew for all users?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `/usr/local/bin` to the environment variable `PATH`.

There is many ways to accomplish this. You can configure it in the global properties (*Manage Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global Properties*) or use plugin such as [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) or even simply set it in the beginning of the script block, e.g.

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```